# unable to solve basic hurdle compiling with eclipse luna and equinox (newbie)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, equinox

I'm working my way through getting started with EclipseSCADA http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseSCADA/GettingStarted/SettingUpAScadaProject and when I get to the last step - running the application with:

```
Run -> Run Equinox Application Profile
```

It fails with error:

> Missing 3 installable units in the target platform: [org.eclipse.equinox.server.core, org.eclipse.equinox.server.p2, org.eclipse.equinox.server.jetty]

I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to resolve these dependencies.  Been on google for hours with no joy.

I've downloaded the equinox-Luna_SDK zip file which contains the above mentioned plugins, but I don't know how to get Eclipse to see them.

Any help or pointers on this would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the same issue when following http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseSCADA/GettingStarted/SettingUpAScadaProject.

> The problem is how to install the missing installable units.

After searching for a long day, I get the solution finally.

## Step 1. Download KeplerSR2 Package

address - http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR2-201402211700/

[image]

## Step 2. Install KeplerSR2 Package

From eclipse, navigate to "Help --> Install new software", work with this url `http://123.57.138.177/equinox-SDK-KeplerSR2/`.

> note, In this url, I host the unzipped KeplerSR2 package since it is a p2 repo. Also, please uncheck the **Group items by category**.

[image]

Then, you should get a list like below.
[image]

Just select them all and click finish. It bring you to install them.

## Step 3 check the installations after restart

When the plugins and features are installed, a dialog is popup and ask for restarting. After restarting, go to "Eclipse --> Preferences --> Plug-in Development --> Target Platform"
[image]

Click **edit**, then query the missing installable units.
Now, they are resolved.

[image]

## Start modbus.profile.xml finally

With the GetStart Guide, I get something like this.
[image]

To launch the modbus simulator, start it as a equinox application.
[image]

## Other useful links

- book

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0321585712?ie=UTF8&tag=equinoxosgior-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=0321585712](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321585712)

- download

http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR2-201402211700/

- set plugin platform target

http://www.xdemo.org/osgi-equinox-environment/

- RCP Best Practices – Set up a target platform

http://www.modumind.com/2012/10/23/rcp-best-practices-set-up-a-target-platform/

- hello world

http://www.xdemo.org/osgi-hello-world/

- build system EclipseTycho

  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#maventycho_overview
- Install KeplerSR2

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Zipped_Repos
http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-KeplerSR2-201402211700/

```
Note: Please see bug bug 268210 for issues related to provisioning from these repos for your PDE target. Currently, you can't provision from these repos in PDE because the repository browser doesn't show categories.
```

If you select by `group by category`, it displays nothing. So, the category should be unmarked.

Answer (score 0):

Open Preferences -> Plugin Development -> Target Platform. There you see your target platforms and can edit them.
In edit mode you can add locations where to find bundles and choose which bundles to include.